# d3 tree diagram with straight links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, treeview, data-visualization

I'm creating a tree diagram with both tree and radial visualization.

I'm using

```
var radialDiagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });
```

and

```
 var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.x, d.y];
  });
```

to render the links between the nodes, but i'd like it to be straight and not rounded.

Am i missing something?

Here is a jsfiddle of my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/burro92/j4q5yf7m/

Answer (score 0):

To render the links with straight lines you just have to set the `d` attribute of the `<path>` to form straight lines between the nodes.
`d` ,however, is coincidentally also the d3.js convention for naming the argument for callback functions which are passed to functions like `selection.attr()` or `selection.style()` functions. The latter `d` argument refers to the data which is attached to the selections. 
For tree layout, you can access the position of one node with `d.source.x` and `d.source.y` and the position of the other node with `d.target.x and d.target.y`, respectively. 
See https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_links:

> node.links()
>
> Returns an array of links for this node, where each link is an object
>   that defines source and target properties. The source of each link is
>   the parent node, and the target is a child node.

In your case, you just define a function to create the correct d attribute for each link:

```
var straight = d => "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
      + "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
```

and then call that funtion when ýou draw the paths for the links:

```
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .style('stroke', '#8da0cb')
      .attr('d', straight);
```

Here your example with a straight line tree:

```js
   function findColor(info) {
      if (info.data.color) return info.data.color;
      if (info.parent) return findColor(info.parent)
      return '#ccc';
    }

    function transitionToRadialTree() {

      var nodes = radialTree.nodes(root), // recalculate layout
        links = radialTree.links(nodes);

      svg.transition().duration(duration)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' +
          (height / 2) + ')');
      // set appropriate translation (origin in middle of svg)

      link.data(links)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style('stroke', '#fc8d62')
        .attr('d', radialDiagonal); //get the new radial path

      node.data(nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
          return 'rotate(' + (d.x - 90) + ')translate(' + d.y + ')';
        });

      node.select('circle')
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style('stroke', '#984ea3');

    };

    function transitionToTree(isStraight) {

      var nodes = tree.nodes(root), //recalculate layout
        links = tree.links(nodes);

      svg.transition().duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      link.data(links)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style('stroke', '#e78ac3')
        .attr('d', isStraight ? straight : diagonal); // get the new tree path

      node.data(nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
          return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
        });

      node.select('circle')
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style('stroke', '#377eb8');

    };

    const root =
    {
      name: 'Main',
      color: '#00FF00',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'First level A',
          color: '#F5FF8A',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Second level A',
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'Third level A',
                  children: [
                    {
                      name: 'Fourth level A',
                    },
                    {
                      name: 'Fourth level B',
                    }
                  ]
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          color: '#DA59FF',
          name: 'First level B',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Second level B',
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'Third level B',
                  children: [
                    {
                      name: 'Fourth level A',
                    }
                  ]
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'First level C',
          color: '#FA935A',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Second level C',
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'Third level C',
                  children: [
                    {
                      name: 'Fourth level A',
                    },
                    {
                      name: 'Fourth level B',
                    }
                  ]
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    };

    // set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 0 };
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var diameter = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var duration = 300;


    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([height, width - 160]);

    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
      .size([height, width - 160]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
      .projection(function (d) {
        return [d.x, d.y];
      });

    // var straight = d => "M" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y
    //  + "V" + d.source.y + "H" + d.source.x;

    var straight = d => "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
      + "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
  
    var radialTree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([360, diameter / 2])
      .separation(function (a, b) {
        return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
      });
      

    var radialCluster = d3.layout.cluster()
      .size([360, diameter / 2])
      .separation(function (a, b) {
        return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
      });

    var radialDiagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
      .projection(function (d) {
        return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
      });


    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');


    // var root = getData(),
    var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);
    var links = cluster.links(nodes);

    var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .style('stroke', '#8da0cb')
      .attr('d', diagonal);

    var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      
      .attr('class', 'node')
      
      .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
      })

    node.append('circle')
      .attr('r', 4.5)
      .style('stroke', '#e41a1c');
/*
            node.append('text')
                .attr('dx', function (d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
                .attr('dy', 3)
                .style('text-anchor', function (d) { return d.children ? 'end' : 'start'; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
        */
    // renderTree();
```

```css
  /* set the CSS */
  body {
    background-color: #181833;
  }

  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    /* stroke: steelblue; */
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }

  .node text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    fill: #ccc;
  }

  /* .node--internal text {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  }*/

  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<meta charset='utf-8'>

  <button onclick='transitionToRadialTree()'>Radial</button>
  <button onclick='transitionToTree(false)'>Tree</button>
  <button onclick='transitionToTree(true)'>straight Tree</button>

  <svg id='hostElement'></svg>
```

What doesn't work well though, is a different question, namely how to smoothly transition between the different representations. The reason is a transition between two arbitrary paths is just smooth if the standard transition can "easily" figure out how to match the "structure" of the initial path to the target path. Your two examples fulfill that criterion since both use a similar path based on the cubic bezier curve. For that you may be looking into something like https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path (but I think this library works with d3.v4)